# Non LiDAR device accuracy in ARKIt

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a test app that is based on sample code from Apple. It puts nodes into 3D space and measures distance between them. This works pretty well on LiDAR devices (iPhone12Pro etc). On iPhone11 (non LiDAR) the node is not always positioned on a plane and is too close to camera and does not change focus square to horizontal or vertical plane alignment.
I have checked the Default measure app from Apple and this puts nodes correctly on planes and detects planes alignment correctly.
It also detects environment quicker on non lidar devices compared sample app.

I have sample code like below for getting world position from screen position.

```
/// Convert screen 2D coordinate to 3D world postion
    func screenToWorld(point: CGPoint) -> simd_float3? {
        if hasLidarSupport {
            guard sceneView.session.currentFrame != nil else { return nil }
            guard let raycastQuery = sceneView.raycastQuery(from: point, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any) else { return nil }
            let raycastResults = sceneView.session.raycast(raycastQuery)
            guard let result = raycastResults.first else { return nil }
            let worldCoordinates = simd_float3(result.worldTransform.columns.3.x, result.worldTransform.columns.3.y, result.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
            return worldCoordinates
        }else {
            let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(point, types: [.estimatedVerticalPlane, .estimatedHorizontalPlane, .existingPlane, .existingPlaneUsingExtent, .existingPlaneUsingGeometry]) 
                    if let result = hitTestResults.first {
                        let worldCoordinates = simd_float3(x: result.worldTransform.columns.3.x, y: result.worldTransform.columns.3.y, z: result.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
                        return worldCoordinates
                    }
                    return nil
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: i fixed adding nodes now by adding below, seems to work ok on LiDAR without that but not on non LiDAR. However it takes longer still to detect environment in sample app compared to the measure app, why would it be the case? `worldtracking.planeDetection = [.horizontal,.vertical]`